# Error al crear una imagen en Java Netbeans [Java 18 - Netbeans 15]

Tags: netbeans, java-swing, java-18

necesito ayuda con este error porfavor, yo soy nuevo desarrollando en java y netbeans, lo que estoy empezando a hacer es un login, y para eso necesito colocar una imagen que esta ubicado dentro del proyecto, pero este error que sale en la consola me detuvo.

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project restaurante: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Para ubicar una imagen dentro del proyecto uso este método **getClass.getResource**.
El error es causado probablemente en la línea donde se hace uso de ese método, porque cuando ubico una imagen que esta fuera del proyecto, se carga todo bien.
A continuación, coloco como se ven las dos líneas de código. (la línea comentada es el que causa el error)

> // ImageIcon imagenLogo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/logo.png"));

> ImageIcon imagenLogo = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Toshiba/Pictures/Saved Pictures/logo.png");

A continuación, dejo como se ven las carpetas del proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación, dejo como se ve todo el código donde estoy trabajando.

```js
package presentacion;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FrmLogin extends JFrame {
    
    // declaramos componentes y variables
    private JLabel etiquetaUsuario, etiquetaClave, etiquetaLogo;
    private JTextField inputUsuario;
    private JPasswordField inputClave;
    private JButton btnIngresar, btnCancelar;
    
    public FrmLogin() {
        setTitle("Inicio de Sesion");
        setSize(500, 250);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    //para cerrar
        setLayout(null);    //null xq las coordenadas seran manuales
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);    //para que este centrado en la pantalla.
        
        //creamos componentes
        etiquetaUsuario = new JLabel("Usuario:");
        inputUsuario = new JTextField();
        etiquetaClave = new JLabel("Contraseña:");
        inputClave = new JPasswordField();
        btnIngresar = new JButton("Ingresar");
        btnCancelar = new JButton("Cancelar");
        etiquetaLogo = new JLabel();
        
        //crear icono
//        ImageIcon imagenLogo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/logo.png"));
        ImageIcon imagenLogo = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Toshiba/Pictures/Saved Pictures/logo.png");
        
        //asignamos iconos
        etiquetaLogo.setIcon(imagenLogo);
        
        //agregamos componentes
        add(etiquetaUsuario);
        add(inputUsuario);
        add(etiquetaClave);
        add(inputClave);
        add(btnIngresar);
        add(btnCancelar);
        add(etiquetaLogo);
        
        //asignamos posiciones
        etiquetaLogo.setBounds(20, 20, 150, 150);
        
        etiquetaUsuario.setBounds(220, 50, 100, 25);
        inputUsuario.setBounds(340, 50, 130, 25);
        
        etiquetaClave.setBounds(220,90, 100, 25);
        inputClave.setBounds(340, 90, 130, 25);
        
        btnIngresar.setBounds(220,140, 100, 25);
        btnCancelar.setBounds(360, 140, 100, 25);
    }
}
```

A continuación, dejo como se todo ve el pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>restaurante</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.mycompany.restaurante.Restaurante</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Intenta con `.getResource("../Imagenes/logo.png")`

Comment: por que inicias con una barra? si sabes que eso generalmente indica la raíz de tu sistema de ficheros?